# ACF query-pass field value

Tags: wp-query, advanced-custom-fields

I'm trying to pass ACF field value in query as value. Let me show what I have now:

```
array(                              
    'key' => 'office', // name of custom field
    'value' => '320', // matches exaclty "123", not just 123. This prevents a match for "1234"
    'compare' => 'LIKE'
),
```

As you see, I have static value now, this is an ID of post object. The problem is that this is not always "320", so I've created another relationship to choose which office you want. But now I'm confused how to pass that field value into query. I tried something like this but it return all users from all offices

```
$valuee = get_field( "choose_office" );
$args = array(
    'meta_query' => array(
        array(
            'key' => 'office', // name of custom field
            'value' => $valuee, // matches exaclty "123", not just 123. This prevents a match for "1234"
            'compare' => 'LIKE'
        ),
    ),  
);
```

Comment: Is your variable really called `$valuee` or is it a typo? And why do you use `LIKE` as compare method, if you want only exact matches?

Comment: it is really valuee, well i used  reverse query approach from acf documentation they use like, so i used also and there is no problem for now, i get correct results until now.
https://www.advancedcustomfields.com/resources/querying-relationship-fields/    -revese query approach

Comment: And what is the type of this field? Is it relationship field? In such case get_field will return an array, so your query won't work...

Comment: Yes it is relationship field, ok, any sugestion about this?

Comment: So i find answer in another question on stack:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46816190/using-post-id-inside-reverse-acf-relationship-querie

Answer (score 0, accepted):

SOLUTION:

```
$posts = get_field('choose_office'); if( $posts ): 
 foreach(array_slice($posts, 0, 1) as $post):
  setup_postdata($post);
  $post_ID =  get_the_ID();
   endforeach; 
   wp_reset_postdata();
   endif;

  $args = array(


'meta_query' => array(

        array(

'key' => 'office', // name of custom field-post object
'value' => $post_ID, //name of relationship field
'compare' => 'LIKE'
                            ),

                        ),  
    );
```

Solution from question:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46816190/using-post-id-inside-reverse-acf-relationship-querie